# nancyfx unreachable exist file

Tags: c#, nancy

I use nancyfx.
I have published a folder with files. 
I start the server and observe the following situation:

1. If there is a file '1.html' in the published folder, then I get it through the browser. If I delete this file from the disk, I get an error 404 (this is correct). If I add this file to disk again, or I change its contents, I normally get it in the browser.
2. **If after starting the server I try to access from the browser to a nonexistent file '2.html', I get an error 404 (This is correct). However, if after that I create the file '2.html' on the disk, I still get a 404 error. It helps only restart the server.**

I got the impression that nancyfx at the first access to the requested files forms some kind of cache, which subsequently does not allow me to get the files added after they were unsuccessfully requested.

Help please with the decision of the given problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nancy uses a convention based approach for figuring out what static content it is able to serve at runtime. you can check the [Documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content) here